# react-native run-ios gives this error

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

#### Issue

When I run `react-native run-ios`

I get the following error:

```
In file included from /Users/zoe/Developer/fireClient/node_modules/react-native-overlay/RNClickThroughWindow.m:2:
../react-native/React/Views/RCTView.h:21:1: error: duplicate interface definition for class 'RCTView'
@interface RCTView : UIView
^
In file included from /Users/zoe/Developer/fireClient/node_modules/react-native-overlay/RNClickThroughWindow.m:2:
In file included from ../react-native/React/Views/RCTView.h:15:
/Users/zoe/Developer/fireClient/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-
```

... and more here: https://justpaste.it/18vvl

I am wondering what I can do to solve this.

I have upgraded to the latest version of RN and I have linked all my packages.

Comment: This is because you are using react-native-overlay. Please don't use this repo as suggested on the README. You can accomplish what you are trying to do using absolute positioning and z-index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you can remove `react-native-overlay` from `node_module`. And try again to install `npm install react-native-overlay --save`. Or you can upgrade before to RN 0.40.

i think your question is same with this #Issue [463](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/issues/463).

hope i can help you.

Comment: I tried deleting the module all together and it still does not work.

Comment: Ok, So I then deleted the linking in Xcode and this fixed the problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you please share how did you do this?